# Integrating Disqus to Android app

Tags: android, disqus

I want to add disqus to my android app.
I traced and found the code for displaying the disqus comments with id and short name.
But I am not able to find documents for adding the secret and public key. Then go forward.

Already registered in Disqus, got my private and public key.
Now I need to know,

```
1. Where to add the keys to the app.
2. How do I create id mapping to a particular page(activity/fragment).
3. Where am I supposed to give the short name?
```

Answer (score 5):

@ndgreen, doesn't work anymore ! Cross domains security provide to load the external JS. We have to do this now :

```
String htmlComments = getHtmlComment("idPost", "youriddisqus");

yourWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://youriddisqus.disqus.com/", htmlComments, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

public String getHtmlComment(String idPost, String shortName) {

    return "<html><head></head><body><div id='disqus_thread'></div></body>"
        + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
        + "var disqus_identifier = '"
        + idPost
        + "';"
        + "var disqus_shortname = '"
        + shortName
        + "';"
        + " (function() { var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;"
        + "dsq.src = '/embed.js';"
        + "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();"
        + "</script></html>";
}
```

And voila !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = 'linkOFPage'
this.page.identifier = 'page_identifier';
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = '//forumName.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
```

then made activity as--

```
webDisqus = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.disqus);
    //set up disqus
WebSettings webSettings2 = webDisqus.getSettings();

webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webSettings2.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

webDisqus.requestFocusFromTouch();
String htmlComments = getHtmlComment(url, "forumName");
webDisqus.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(htmlComments,"text/html", null, ""));

webDisqus.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webDisqus.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://forumName.disqus.com/",htmlComments,"text/html","UTF-8","");


 public String getHtmlComment(String idPost, String shortName) {
  return "<html><head></head><body><div id='disqus_thread'></div></body>" + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
           + "var disqus_identifier = '" + idPost + "';" + "var disqus_shortname = '" + shortName + "';"
           + "var disqus_config = function () {this.page.identifier='" + idPost + "';" + "}" + ";"
           + " (function() { var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;"
           + "dsq.src = '/embed.js';"
           + "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();"
           + "</script></html>";
```

}

custom web view client file--

```
  public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
  {
   private String html_comments, sType, obj, sMyURL;
   public MyWebViewClient(String htmlComments, String string, String object, String URL) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  html_comments = htmlComments;
  sType = string;
  obj = object;
  sMyURL = URL;
 }
  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
  Log.i("page started", url);
   }

  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
  Log.i("disqus error", "failed: " + failingUrl + ", error code: " + errorCode + " [" + description + "]");
  }

 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

   if (url.indexOf("logout") > -1 || url.indexOf("disqus.com/next/login-success") > -1) {
     view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://forumName.disqus.com/", html_comments, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
     }

  if (url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/twitter/complete") > -1 || url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/facebook/complete") > -1
           || url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/google/complete") > -1) {
     view.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/login.php");
  }

   if (url.indexOf("file:///android_res/raw/login.php") > -1) {
     view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://forumName.disqus.com/", html_comments, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
  }}
```

finally i made a raw folder in res and saved ablank file by name login.php

hope this helps someone.
thanks to globe totter